# How to Assign two function to a single toggle button in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to change a button name once it is clicked. There are two functions differently Add and Subtract. first-time button name is 'Add', when it clicked it should execute add number function and then name dynamically change button name to Subtract, and once I clicked to subtract it should execute subtract function and again the name of a button come to Add which is previous. How can I do this? how to call a different function like add function when button toggle is add and vice versa.

now I can toggle between two buttons but facing issues with calling add and subtract functions.

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">
      {{ toggle ? 'Add' : 'Subtract' }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Varsha, Could you please check this working fiddle. Do you want this?

**Explanation:** You can use a flag (functionToBeCalled in this case) to call the targeted function and switch the text of the button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

 <button ng-click="functionToBeCalled == 'Add' ? add() : substract();">
      {{ functionToBeCalled }}
    </button>
<br>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.functionToBeCalled = "Add";
    $scope.add = function() {
     $scope.functionToBeCalled = "Substract";
        alert('Add is clicked');
    };
    
    $scope.substract = function() {
     $scope.functionToBeCalled = "Add";
        alert('Substract is clicked');
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have 2 buttons defined and show one of them at a time using `ng-if`. `ng-if` removes the button from the DOM if the condition is not met. See the official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

```html
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-if="toggle" ng-click="add()">
      Add
    </button>

    <button ng-if="!toggle" ng-click="subtract()">
      Subtract
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```